# How do change the data and layout in a collectionview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a collectionview controller. I would like to reuse it. I have a two custom collectionviewlayouts, each has its own data source.

What steps and in what order, do I take to change the layouts and datasource?

My CollectionView controller is as follows:

```
- (id)initWithCollectionViewLayout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)layout {
    self = [super initWithCollectionViewLayout:layout];
    if (self) {
        self.dataSource = [[WeekDataSource alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)loadView {
    [super loadView];
    [self setupCollectionView];
}
- (void)setupCollectionView {
    self.collectionView = [[CalendarView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame collectionViewLayout:self.collectionViewLayout];
    self.collectionView.dataSource = self.dataSource;
    self.collectionView.delegate = self.dataSource;
    self.collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}
```

The controller displays the collection view just fine, using my custom layout which derives from `UICollectionViewLayout`.

What I am having troubles with, is changing out the layout, and the datasource which it depends on.

I have tried, the following, but for some reason the collectionView insists on using the old collectionViewLayout.

```
self.dataSource = [[DayDataSource alloc] initWithScheduleNumber:0];
self.collectionView.dataSource = self.dataSource;
self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout;
```

edit: I have discovered that `self.collectionViewLayout` of the UICollectionViewController is a read-only attribute. Does that mean the controller is not intended to be reused in this way? (reused by having its layout and datasource switched out during runtime)? I figure that it is pointing to the layout which was used to initialise the controller, thus the issue with the view trhing to use the old layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this one out.

Here is the code which allowed the controlled to be reused.

```
- (void)switchToViewMode:(NSInteger)viewMode {
    UICollectionViewLayout *layout;
    CalendarView *view;
    CGRect oldFrame;
        switch (viewMode) {
            case 0:
            case 1:
                layout = [[DayCollectionViewLayout alloc] initWithCoder:nil];
                oldFrame = self.collectionView.frame;
                view = [[CalendarView alloc] initWithFrame:oldFrame collectionViewLayout:layout];
                self.dataSource = [[DayDataSource alloc] initWithScheduleNumber:0]; // TODO set correct date
                view.dataSource = self.dataSource;
                view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
                self.collectionView = view;
                break;

            case 2:
                layout = [[WeekCollectionViewLayout alloc] initWithCoder:nil];
                oldFrame = self.collectionView.frame;
                view = [[CalendarView alloc] initWithFrame:oldFrame collectionViewLayout:layout];
                self.dataSource = [[WeekDataSource alloc] init];
                view.dataSource = self.dataSource;
                view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
                self.collectionView = view;
                break;

            default:
                    @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:NSInternalInconsistencyException
                                                   reason:@"Unknown view mode selected." userInfo:nil];
                break;
        }
}
```